# Can't override phtml template, displays blank page

Tags: magento2, customer-address, template-override

I have override

> vendor/magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/view/frontend/templates/customer/address/edit.phtml

and placed the replaced file in:

> app/design/frontend/ParentTheme/childTheme/Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes/templates/customer/address/edit.phtml

but I see blank page in the respective page.

can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: module-customer-custom-attributes folder does not exist in Magento vendor/magento folder. Please check once again.

Answer (score 0):

Natively, this module doesn't exist, but if you have it, you can override it in your theme like this :

> app/design/frontend/Package/themename/Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes/templates/customer/address/edit.phtml